# Animating value node of a material so I see keyframes in timeline

Tags: animation, node-editor

I want to animate alpha using value node but when I add keyframe I dont see any material in timeline and no keyframe appears.[image]

Comment: It looks as if you need to have the Shader editor open with the Value node selected to see the keyframes on the Timeline.

Comment: The shader editor doesn't need to be opened, but the node with the animation needs to be selected when leaving shader editor.

Comment: Or turn off "Only Show Selected" (the highlighted arrow icon at the top-right of the Dope Sheet) if you want to see it without selecting it.

Comment: The node had to be selected, and I find useful also option with dope sheet. Thank you!